# C++: indirect invocation of `delete this` in event driven system (e.g. in GUI application)

Tags: c++, user-interface, event-handling

I was working for a while with different C++ GUI frameworks (e.g. Qt, wxWidgets, also some proprietary) but cannot decide for myself regarding the topic described below.

As discussed in several questions/answers here, direct use of `delete this` is valid in C++ (as long as you don't dereference `this` any more), but it is in most cases not good idea.

But in some cases, object invokes its destructor indirectly. This situation specifically often arise in event drive systems (GUI applications come to mind first).

```
class Kernel {
public:
    void Start() {
        _window = new Window();
    }
    void OnCloseButton() {
        if (_window) {
            _window->Close();
            delete _window;
            _window = NULL;
        }
private:
    MyWindow * _window;
};

class MyWindow
{
public:
    MyWindow(Kernel & kernel) : _kernel(&kernel) {
        Connect(my_button_close_event, this, OnCloseButtonClicked);
    }
    OnCloseButtonClicked() {
        // This call actually calls destructor of this object.
        _kernel->OnCloseButton();
        // If we access any fields of Window here, we're going to have problems
    }
private:
    Kernel * _kernel;
};
```

Notice: I did not try to compile the code - it may have typos or bad practices. But it should illustrate the idea.

So, the question is: Is it OK to do something like in the example above: the handler of the event calls some other function (method of its owner), which indirectly deletes `this`?

Or should I better make the `Kernel` class event aware and connect the event from the button directly to the method in the `Kernel` and then we do not have this situation of indirect call to `delete this`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do so since the Window instance is created by the Start() method but it's a bad practice in Object Oriented Programming.